# How to find internal sd card path?

Tags: android

I am beginner in android. How to find the path of internal sd card and then how to find their used spaces and free spaces. Please reply your comments and answers are valuable me.

Comment: You might want to check out, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html could have some useful information for you.

Answer (score 2):

> How to find Internal SD Card Path and External SD Card Path

You don't.

At this time, from the Android SDK's standpoint, there is no "Internal SD Card Path" or "External SD Card Path". There is the path to external storage, which is returned by the various methods on `Environment` (e.g., `getExternalStorageDirectory()`). That will be whatever storage the device manufacturer designated for this purpose.

There is no reliable means of determining any other potential "SD Card Path" on an Android device.

Comment: Thanks for Inforamtion. It's useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

Check the android docs on accessing the sd card: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Answer (score 0):

Use below code it will return you list of internal directories path and sdcard path for those devices having both internal and external storage.

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getParent());
            File[] f = dir.listFiles();
            for(File file:f)
        {
            if(file.getName().equals("sdacard0"))//check name of sdcard from  file manager.
            {
                if(file.isDirectory())
                {
                    f = file.listFiles();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's always `System.getenv(ENV_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)`  from `android.os`:

Other Examples from source code:

```
public static File getExternalStorageDirectory() {
    throwIfUserRequired();
    return sCurrentUser.getExternalDirs()[0];
}

/** {@hide} */
public static File getLegacyExternalStorageDirectory() {
    return new File(System.getenv(ENV_EXTERNAL_STORAGE));
}

/** {@hide} */
public static File getLegacyExternalStorageObbDirectory() {
    return buildPath(getLegacyExternalStorageDirectory(), DIR_ANDROID, DIR_OBB);
}
```

---

**Environment.java**

```
private static final String ENV_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = "EXTERNAL_STORAGE";
private static final String ENV_ANDROID_ROOT = "ANDROID_ROOT";
private static final String ENV_ANDROID_DATA = "ANDROID_DATA";
private static final String ENV_ANDROID_EXPAND = "ANDROID_EXPAND";
private static final String ENV_ANDROID_STORAGE = "ANDROID_STORAGE";
private static final String ENV_DOWNLOAD_CACHE = "DOWNLOAD_CACHE";
private static final String ENV_OEM_ROOT = "OEM_ROOT";
private static final String ENV_ODM_ROOT = "ODM_ROOT";
private static final String ENV_VENDOR_ROOT = "VENDOR_ROOT";

/** {@hide} */
public static final String DIR_ANDROID = "Android";
private static final String DIR_DATA = "data";
private static final String DIR_MEDIA = "media";
private static final String DIR_OBB = "obb";
private static final String DIR_FILES = "files";
private static final String DIR_CACHE = "cache";

/** {@hide} */
@Deprecated
public static final String DIRECTORY_ANDROID = DIR_ANDROID;

private static final File DIR_ANDROID_ROOT = getDirectory(ENV_ANDROID_ROOT, "/system");
private static final File DIR_ANDROID_DATA = getDirectory(ENV_ANDROID_DATA, "/data");
private static final File DIR_ANDROID_EXPAND = getDirectory(ENV_ANDROID_EXPAND, "/mnt/expand");
private static final File DIR_ANDROID_STORAGE = getDirectory(ENV_ANDROID_STORAGE, "/storage");
private static final File DIR_DOWNLOAD_CACHE = getDirectory(ENV_DOWNLOAD_CACHE, "/cache");
private static final File DIR_OEM_ROOT = getDirectory(ENV_OEM_ROOT, "/oem");
private static final File DIR_ODM_ROOT = getDirectory(ENV_ODM_ROOT, "/odm");
private static final File DIR_VENDOR_ROOT = getDirectory(ENV_VENDOR_ROOT, "/vendor");
```

---

**Source**

[sources\android-25\android\os\Environment.java](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/refs/heads/master/sdk/sources/android-25/android/os/Environment.java)