# Delete folders starting with "." android

Tags: java, android, directory

I can delete the contents of a particular directory using the code below, but I want to delete only the folders/files whose names start with a "." instead. For instance: .aptoide, .adobe, .dcim

```
package com.example.deleter;
import java.io.File;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/CHO/D2");
        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
                String[] children = dir.list();
                for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                    new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: i want it to remove all the folders starting with "." from the internal sd card

Answer (score 4):

You can get the root directory of the external storage with just `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. You can check if the filename starts with `.` with [`startsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)):

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
if (dir.isDirectory()) {
    String[] children = dir.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i].startsWith(".")) {
            new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
        }
    }
}
```

or, equivalenty, with [`charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)):

```
if (children[i].charAt(0) == '.') {
```

Comment: The root directory of what? You control that with `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/CHO/D2"` - change it to the root directory instead.

Comment: 'Internal SD card' - that could just be `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. Otherwise, have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070135/how-to-find-internal-sd-card-path).

Comment: I missed some lines, after your suggestion of adding the `File` instantiation. This is fixed now.

Comment: My mistake - `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` already returns a File, not a String.

Comment: allright, the edit is error-free but it does not delete any "." Folders from the internal SD card, could it be the children issue?

Comment: I'm not sure. Might also be a permission issue. `delete()` returns a boolean - can you check what values it returns?

Comment: im not sure about that actually but i have all the internal and external sd card read/write permissions

Answer (score 2):

did you try the following:

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/CHO/D2");
if (dir.isDirectory()) {
   String[] children = dir.list();
   for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
       String name = children[i];
       if (name.startsWith(".") {
           new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: i want it to remove all the folders starting with "." from the internal sd card